# How to handle with 'Policy CMP0074 is not set' warning while using Cmake to build PCL tutorials?

Tags: c++, cmake, point-cloud-library

I want to complete this basic tutorial:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php#writing-pcd

Its very simple. When I prepare `CMakeLists.txt` and `.cpp` file, I run them with CMake GUI and I get this warning. I installed PCL 1.9.1 so I build file for Visual Studio 2017 64x.

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0 to target Windows 10.0.17763.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26726.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26726.0
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:5(find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

    Environment variable PCL_ROOT is set to:

      C:\libraries\PCL 1.9.1

   For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable. This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Found Eigen: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Eigen/eigen3
Eigen found (include: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Eigen/eigen3, version: 3.3.5)
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE
Found Boost: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/include/boost-1_68 (found suitable version "1.68.0", minimum required is "1.40.0") found components: system filesystem thread date_time iostreams serialization chrono atomic regex
Found FLANN: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s.lib   FLANN found (include: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/include, lib: optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s-gd.lib)
FLANN found (include: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/include, lib: optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s-gd.lib)
Found OpenNI2: C:/libraries/OpenNI2/Lib/OpenNI2.lib
OpenNI2 found (include: C:/libraries/OpenNI2/Include, lib: C:/libraries/OpenNI2/Lib/OpenNI2.lib)
OpenNI2 found (include: C:/libraries/OpenNI2/Include, lib: C:/libraries/OpenNI2/Lib/OpenNI2.lib)
Found Qhull: optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic_d.lib
QHULL found (include: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Qhull/include, lib: optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic_d.lib)
looking for PCL_COMMON
Found PCL_COMMON: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_common_release.lib  
looking for PCL_KDTREE
Found PCL_KDTREE: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_kdtree_release.lib   looking for PCL_OCTREE
Found PCL_OCTREE: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_octree_release.lib  
looking for PCL_SEARCH
Found PCL_SEARCH: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_search_release.lib
looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
Found PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_sample_consensus_release.lib
looking for PCL_FILTERS
Found PCL_FILTERS: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_filters_release.lib 
looking for PCL_2D
Found PCL_2D: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/include/pcl-1.9
looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
Found PCL_GEOMETRY: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/include/pcl-1.9
looking for PCL_IO
Found PCL_IO: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_io_release.lib
looking for PCL_FEATURES
Found PCL_FEATURES: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_features_release.lib   looking for PCL_ML
Found PCL_ML: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_ml_release.lib
looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
Found PCL_SEGMENTATION: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_segmentation_release.lib
looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
Found PCL_VISUALIZATION: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_visualization_release.lib
looking for PCL_SURFACE
Found PCL_SURFACE: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_surface_release.lib 
looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
Found PCL_REGISTRATION: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_registration_release.lib
looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
Found PCL_KEYPOINTS: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_keypoints_release.lib
looking for PCL_TRACKING
Found PCL_TRACKING: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_tracking_release.lib  
looking for PCL_RECOGNITION
Found PCL_RECOGNITION: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_recognition_release.lib
looking for PCL_STEREO
Found PCL_STEREO: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_stereo_release.lib  
looking for PCL_OUTOFCORE
Found PCL_OUTOFCORE: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_outofcore_release.lib
looking for PCL_PEOPLE
Found PCL_PEOPLE: C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/lib/pcl_people_release.lib
Found PCL: pcl_common;pcl_kdtree;pcl_octree;pcl_search;pcl_sample_consensus;pcl_filters;pcl_io;pcl_features;pcl_ml;pcl_segmentation;pcl_visualization;pcl_surface;pcl_registration;pcl_keypoints;pcl_tracking;pcl_recognition;pcl_stereo;pcl_outofcore;pcl_people;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_thread-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_regex-vc141-mt-x64-1_68.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Boost/lib/libboost_regex-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/Qhull/lib/qhullstatic_d.lib;C:/libraries/OpenNI2/Lib/OpenNI2.lib;optimized;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s.lib;debug;C:/libraries/PCL 1.9.1/3rdParty/FLANN/lib/flann_cpp_s-gd.lib;vtksys;vtkCommonCore;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonMisc;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonColor;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkFiltersCore;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkImagingCore;vtkImagingFourier;vtkalglib;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkInfovisCore;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources;vtkRenderingCore;vtkzlib;vtkfreetype;vtkRenderingFreeType;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkChartsCore;vtkDICOMParser;vtklz4;vtkIOCore;vtkIOLegacy;vtkexpat;vtkIOXMLParser;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOXML;vtkParallelCore;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkImagingSources;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkFiltersPoints;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkFiltersTopology;verdict;vtkFiltersVerdict;vtkmetaio;vtkjpeg;vtkpng;vtktiff;vtkIOImage;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkImagingColor;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkViewsCore;vtkproj4;vtkGeovisCore;vtkhdf5_hl;vtkhdf5;vtkIOAMR;vtkIOEnSight;vtkNetCDF;vtkexoIIc;vtkIOExodus;vtkRenderingOpenGL;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL;vtkgl2ps;vtkRenderingGL2PS;vtklibharu;vtkIOExport;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkIOExportOpenGL;vtkIOGeometry;vtkIOImport;vtklibxml2;vtkIOInfovis;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOMINC;vtkoggtheora;vtkIOMovie;vtknetcdfcpp;vtkIONetCDF;vtkIOPLY;vtkjsoncpp;vtkIOParallel;vtkIOParallelXML;vtksqlite;vtkIOSQL;vtkIOTecplotTable;vtkIOVideo;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkImagingStencil;vtkInteractionImage;vtkRenderingImage;vtkRenderingLIC;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsInfovis (Required is at least version "1.2")
Configuring done
Generating done
```

After build, when I click open project and run it, I get this error.

[image]

Any solution for it?

Comment: When asking a question all relevant details MUST be in the question (links rot) and should be text (images are rendered unusable by [many things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4581301)).

Comment: It's better / preferred if you copy and paste the text of the error message instead of a picture of your GUI.

Comment: The second error message is a user error. The `ALL_BUILD` target is not an executable target so you can't run or debug it. It's purpose to force all projects in the solution to build. Select a executable project as your startup project to fix that.

Comment: @user4581301 sorry I don't have enough points for posting picture

Comment: @drescherjm sorry I am very unexperienced about it. I didn't get what you mean

Comment: ***I didn't get what you mean*** Right click on a target / project in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer  and set the "Set this project as the startup project" to fix the problem. You need to select a project that is an application not `ALL_BUILD` which is not an application.

Comment: The restrictions on posting pictures is partly because you do not want to post a picture. Avoid using images. Too many people cannot see them and they are much more difficult than text to search.

Comment: @user4581301 got it thanks, i will do like that

Comment: @drescherjm oh thank you for the answer, now it says " code can not be run, pcl_io_debug.dll can not be found. Reinstalling the program may solve the problem. "   Do you know anything about this one?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem at al except trying to run the ALL_BUILD target.

Comment: ***Do you know anything about this one?*** You need to set the `PATH` environment variable to have an entry for the folder that contains the mentioned dll files it is asking for or just copy the dlls to the Debug folder where the executable exists.

Comment: @drescherjm PCL 1.9.1 path is already set in environment variable but i will try to put dll files in debug folder. thank you, you are awesome

Comment: @drescherjm I got an error " path is too long " while installing pcl. Maybe its about it but I added paths to environment variables by manually. Do you see any problem here? https://imgur.com/a/1P0yx9L

Comment: You may have to remove some other path in that list. Also you may want to push the bin folder higher.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10

Comment: I don't know which one should I remove, when I put all DLL 's to the debug folder, it worked. Thank you so much, I have spent 2 days while trying to install pcl or use Cmake. You are the only one that answers all my noob and newbie questions. I wish I could do something for you.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you for path link

Comment: This question is common for new users to `CMake` in `Visual Studio`. I have seen it a few times for different `CMake` based projects.

Comment: BTW, the `CMP0074` is not really a problem. It's a warning for the developer of the `CMakeLists.txt` that a behavior in `CMake` has changed. It's really not for the end user to worry so much about.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you, you are awesome

Comment: Please, do not format multiline error messages as a *blockquote*. This formatting doesn't preserve newlines, so the messages becomes hard to understand. Use **code** formatting instead (`Ctrl+K` or `{}` button).

Comment: @Tsyvarev okey i will do that, thank you for warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CMP0074` warning is not really a problem you as a user need to worry about. It's a warning for the developer of the CMakeLists.txt that a behavior in CMake has changed.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0074.html

> In CMake 3.12 and above the find_package() command now
>   searches prefixes specified by the _ROOT CMake variable
>   and the *ROOT environment variable. Package roots are
>   maintained as a stack so nested calls to all find** commands inside
>   find modules also search the roots as prefixes. This policy provides
>   compatibility with projects that have not been updated to avoid using
>   _ROOT variables for other purposes.
>
> The OLD behavior for this policy is to ignore _ROOT
>   variables. The NEW behavior for this policy is to use
>   _ROOT variables.

Basically the warning is that the developers of the `CMakeLists.txt` have not set the policy to enable the new behavior or to keep the old behavior however the `PCL_ROOT` was defined. `CMake` will not automatically use it because the new behavior is not enabled.

The `ALL_BUILD` error message is because the `ALL_BUILD` target / project is not an executable target. It's purpose is to force building of all projects in the solution. To fix that part you need to right click on an executable project / target in the `Solution Explorer` and click "Set this project as the startup project"

Comment: This policy is explicitly set in the next release 1.10.0, so this particular warning will not pop-up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines to the CMakeLists.txt file.

```
if(POLICY CMP0074)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 OLD)
endif()
```