# Unable to have npm run a script that starts testcafe

Tags: reactjs, npm, automated-tests, testcafe, shelljs

I have a React project. I am trying to use an npm script that will run a test using testcafe. This test uses `yargs` and `shelljs`. When I run the tests outside of the `package.json` everything works fine, but when I use `npm run test:local -- --api=local` it does not work and I get an error:

> `ERROR No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive.`

I want to be able to run the script to start my tests. Below is my code. Thank you.

Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "test:local": "node ./test/features/index.js",
}
```

index.js:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const shell = require('shelljs');

if (argv.api === 'local') {
  shell.exec('testcafe chrome:headless login-test.js');
}
```

login-test.js:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import Page from './page-model';

const page = new Page();

fixture`Log In Page`.page(page.loginScreen);

test('Log In', async t => {
  await page.userLogin(t);
});

test('Forgot Password', async t => {
  const forgotLink = Selector('a').withAttribute('href', '/forgot');
  const forgotEmailInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('placeholder', 'Email address');
  const resetModal = Selector('div').withAttribute('class', 'Toast-message').innerText;

  await t
    .click(forgotLink)
    .typeText(forgotEmailInput, 'my@email.co')
    .click(page.submit)
    .expect(resetModal)
    .eql('Password reset sent.');
});

test('Forgot Password - Ready to login link', async t => {
  const forgotLink = Selector('a').withAttribute('href', '/forgot');
  const readyLoginButton = Selector('a').withAttribute('href', '/login');

  await t.click(forgotLink).click(readyLoginButton);
});
```

Comment: Would you please clarify the full path for the `login-test.js` file?

Comment: Yes, it is /Users/name/Development/app/hub/test/features/login-test.js

Comment: Do you use the locally or globally installed TestCafe? I had the same problem until I found that I cannot change the PATH environment variable due to the "This environment variable is too large." error. I fixed it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10) thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar at the moment, but putting the

```
testcafe chrome:headless login-test.js
```

command directly into the scripts section of package.json.