# Environment variables not working properly

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I'm trying to run an application that reads an environment variable that contains a JSON with about 22k characters. The project setup tells me to use `$(cat ./path/to/file)` to correctly configure it, but as I'm using windows, this commands do not work.

I've tried copying the contents of the file to the variable using the GUI Environment Variable, but its input truncates the value to a certain limit which is not even on half of the file.
After this I tried setting the variable using the Powershell with the command:

```
$env:myvar = iex '$(type path/to/file)'
```

and then saving the result with:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MYVAR', $env:MYVAR, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

After these commands, Powershell is able to print the result correctly but CMD still prints only part of the value when I `echo` it.

This is very odd because the regedit shows the correct value [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090669/6279345).

The application still can't process the value because it is not complete.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: "a[n] environment variable that contains a JSON with about 22k characters." is _never_ going to work on Windows (env var values must fit in <8192 bytes each and <32768 bytes in total per process)

Comment: the total bytes in process might be the problem. But if each env var must be less than ~8k, how is regedit showing the correct full value?

Comment: "application that reads an environment variable" - what application, and can it read this data in some other way than (ab)using an environment variable?

Comment: Why dont you install Wsl(Windows Subsystem for Linux) and use linux commands

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, these limits aren't quite correct as such - please see my answer.

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/); in your case, use `$env:myvar = Get-Content -Raw path/to/file`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it is a web application using Spring Boot. I Guess it is not possible to configure this project on windows native shells like CMD and PowerShell.
I managed to get the project running by executing it with Intellij and overriding the required environment variable within the IDE.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart but no, I can't change the way the application reads the information because this is a huge project and would require many requests to the managers of the project :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Note: This answer applies to *Windows*.</sup>

**tl;dr**

- While you can *store* up to `32,766` characters in a single environment variable, the standard *retrieval* mechanisms in `cmd.exe` and PowerShell / .NET (as of v7.1 / 5.0) support only up to `4,095`.
- A workaround in PowerShell is possible, but ultimately it comes down to whether the target executable that is meant to read an environment-variable value supports reading values up to the technical maximum length.

---

- The **technical limit for the number of characters in a single environment variable is `32,766`** (`32KB` = `32768`, minus `2`).

  - Starting with Windows Server 2008 / Windows Vista, there is no longer a limit on the *overall* size of the environment block - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables).
- However, **depending on how the environment-variable is *retrieved*, the limit may be lower**:

  - **Both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell, as of v7.1 / .NET 5.0, support retrieving at most `4,095` characters.**
  - However, **in PowerShell you *can* retrieve longer values, assuming the variable of interest is defined persistently in the registry, and assuming that you know whether it is defined at the machine or user level**; e.g., for a `MYVAR` environment variable:

    - At the *machine* level:

      ```
       Get-ItemPropertyValue 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' MYVAR
      ```
    - At the *user* level:

      ```
       Get-ItemPropertyValue registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment MYVAR
      ```

Answer (score 0):

try the type command. It is the windows equivalent of the unix cat command. This means storing the json inside of a seperate file and using the command "type <path_to_file>".

Comment: Yes, I know that. I tried doing so but this is not the problem. Read the question