# How to Set Machine Environment Variable longer than 4095 characters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, registry

I have a very long string I am trying to store in a Machine level Environment Variable.

`Set-Item -Path Env:\...` seems to work, but I dont see a way to set a machine level environment variable with this, only local variables.

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(..., ..., "Machine")`

Has a 4095 character limit and truncates.

```
$Enviro = ([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", $True)
$Enviro.SetValue(..., ..., [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString);
$Enviro.Close()
```

Also seems to have a similar limit and truncates the string.

```
$Enviro = "registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $Enviro -Name ... -Value ...
```

Also, once again, same issue. Truncates to 4095.

What other options do I have?

To people that keep linking the "Environment variables not working properly" article, that doesnt answer this question. That article covers **reading** from the environment/registery, **not** writing to it. This is the exact opposite use case. Please go over my code above and you will notice I tried `Set-ItemProperty` and it **does not** work.

Comment: answered in-depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65693649/8431238)

Comment: This answer is the other way around. I am writing to the Enviro, not reading. When I write and then go look at the produced result via Control Panel, the value is truncated.

As per my statement above, `Set-Item` is working fine, but cannot set machine variables as far as I can see.

Comment: That is the exact same question that was posted at the top, nope, does not answer